# Пинг до серверов

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста со скриптом. Есть тхт файл в котором забиты адреса трех серверов, 10.100.100.1 10.100.100.2 10.100.100.3 . Мне нужно пингом проверить их отклик и если его нет на одном из них удалить из файла этот сервер.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG="/var/log/check_server.log"
SERVER="10.100.100.1"
PING="/sbin/ping"

ping_server() {
${PING} -q -c1 -t1 -s0 ${SERVER} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "${SERVER}" >> ${LOG}
exit 0
else
echo "$0" >> ${LOG}
fi
}
```

Остановился на этом, понимаю что нужно прочитать файл со списком, проверить наличие пинга до всех, найти в списке тот до которого нет пинга и удалить его, а при появлении пинга добавить его, но вот как именно программно реализовать это не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Мне вот интересно, если к кому то пинга нет и Вы его удалили, а потом пинг появился, то как его пинговать будете, что бы добавить? наверное, список будет всегда один, просто будет отдельно список с теми, кто пинговался последний раз.

Вообще то команда ping не предназначена для запуска с скриптов. Для этого есть ее "напарник" - fping (ставиться с репозитария практически в любом линуксе). Эта утилита может взять готовый файл с айпи/именами и пропинговать все. Более того, она умеет возвращать правильные коды возврата. Но на крайний случай, можно просто погрепать вывод.

Навскидку, получилось что то такое  (это если линукс с английской консолью).

```
cat file_with_ip | fping | grep alive | awk '{print $1}'
```

(у утилы есть странность - если запускать не с под рута, то она хочет список айпи только через пайп).

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку! Создал вот такую конструкцию 

>#!/bin/sh
>LOG="/var/log/check_server.log"
>file="/tmp/file_ip"
>BAD="/var/log/bad_ip.log"
>cat ${file} | fping  >> ${LOG}
>cat ${LOG} | grep unreachable | awk '{print $1}' >> ${BAD}
>rm ${LOG}

Проверил на пинг, получил неотвечающий, записал его в другой и теперь хочу взять этот ip и удалить его из файла зоны dns. Логически понимаю что это нужно сделать прочитав файл ${BAD} и если он не пустой тогда найти строку в файле зоны и удалить ее оттуда. Ткните пожалуйста носом, если не трудно. Набираюсь опыта!

Comment: вот Вы хотите сделать по сложному. Делайте по простому. Не нужно удалять. Держите себе список айпи (его можно и отгрепать с файла зоны). Пропинговали, получили список активных. С помощью awk преобразовали его в нужный формат списка. Теперь просто нужно сделать замену. Для этого в исходном файле можно коментариями пометить начало и конец списка. Это сделать просто. Просто распечатываете часть файла до метки, потом свой список, а потом от следующей метки и до конца.  awk/sed  в помощь.